# Passing argument for fopen() in C issues

Tags: c, compiler-errors, scanf, fopen, fgets

I'm working on a function that is supposed to read a file and I need the first line of the text file to be converted to an integer. The function takes the file in as a parameter, char *filename.

However, I'm getting an error when opening the file.

The error is the following: "passing argument of 2 of 'fopen' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] gcc"

```
 FILE *fp = fopen(filename, 'r'); //Line with error

 char str[6]; //since the first line is a 5 digit number
 fgets(str, 6, fp);
 sscanf(str, "%d", *number); //number is the pointer I'm supposed to save this value to, it is also a parameter for the function
```

I'm very new to C. So, I would appreciate any help. Thanks

Comment: you wrote ' instead of "

Comment: I tried changing it to ", but I still get an error.

Comment: @shari What error? `fopen(filename, "r")` should work, assuming that `filename` is valid. (In general, "an error" is just about the least useful description of any error. We need to see the message and the code that caused it.) I'd expect an error on your `sscanf` call, as Vlad's answer mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will look through the description of the function `fopen` you will see that it is declared like

```
FILE *fopen(const char * restrict filename, const char * restrict mode);
```

That is the both parameters have the pointer type `const char *`.

So instead of the integer character constant `'r'` as the second argument you need to use string literal `"r"`

```
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
```

Also you have to write

```
sscanf(str, "%d", &number);
```

instead of

```
sscanf(str, "%d", *number);
```

if `number` has the type `int`. Or if it has the type `int *` then you need to write

```
sscanf(str, "%d", number);
```

And it is desirable to declare the character array as having at least `7` characters to allow to read also the new line character `'\n'` of the record

```
 char str[7]; //since the first line is a 5 digit number
 fgets(str, sizeof( str ), fp);
```

Otherwise a next call of `fgets` can read an empty string.